# Can I use SDL_mixer without SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-mixer

I have a game that uses GLFW for window creation and input. Is it possible to use SDL_mixer for audio without SDL?

Comment: No but it should be possible to use SDL for sound only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, you can't.

Because it depends on SDL headers. At the beginning of SDL_mixer.h there are following lines:

```
#include "SDL_stdinc.h"
#include "SDL_rwops.h"
#include "SDL_audio.h"
#include "SDL_endian.h"
#include "SDL_version.h"
#include "begin_code.h"
```